Python Pandas on_bad_lines - Extending information from 'warn' default warning
Extending on from this stackoverflow question:
Use on_bad_lines to write invalid rows from pandas.read_csv to a file
The default behaviour of on_bad_lines='warn' is to output the following:
2024-11-14 10:06:33,515 - WARNING - C:\xxx\S_EQUI.CSV: Skipping line 46272: expected 82 fields, saw 92
Skipping line 47655: expected 82 fields, saw 172

This is as a result of Pandas method called _alert_malformed, which is:
    def _alert_malformed(self, msg: str, row_num: int) -> None:
        """
        Alert a user about a malformed row, depending on value of
        `self.on_bad_lines` enum.

        If `self.on_bad_lines` is ERROR, the alert will be `ParserError`.
        If `self.on_bad_lines` is WARN, the alert will be printed out.

        Parameters
        ----------
        msg: str
            The error message to display.
        row_num: int
            The row number where the parsing error occurred.
            Because this row number is displayed, we 1-index,
            even though we 0-index internally.
        """
        if self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.ERROR:
            raise ParserError(msg)
        if self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.WARN:
            warnings.warn(
                f"Skipping line {row_num}: {msg}\n",
                ParserWarning,
                stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
            )

How can I extend this method's message and row_no output into the custom callable function that I have made that includes the bad_line?
Current Script:
def write_bad_line(file_path, line, fp, sep=';' ) -> None:
    '''Writes a bad line to a file, then raises a warning'''
    global current_file_path
    if not file_path:
        file_path = current_file_path
    time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    complete_list = [time, str(file_path)] + line
    complete_list = sep.join(complete_list) + '\n'

    fp.write(complete_list)
    warnings.warn(f'Bad Line - number of columns and number of delimiters do not match: {sep.join(line)}', pd.errors.ParserWarning)
    return None

def bad_lines_processor(line: list) -> None:
    '''Wrapper function to process bad lines'''
    global current_file_path, bad_lines_fp
    write_bad_line(file_path=current_file_path, line = line, fp=bad_lines_fp)

bad_lines_fp = open('bad_lines.csv', 'a')

def process_csv_file(file_path, json_data, output_writer, delimiter=';'):
    '''Processes a single CSV file and writes it to the Excel writer.'''

    # Set the current file path for logging purposes
    # set_current_file_path(file_path) # Commented out for debugging purposes.

    tab_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0].replace('.csv', '')

    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=delimiter, header=0, dtype=str, engine='python', on_bad_lines=bad_lines_processor)

        if w:
            for warning in w:
                logger.warning('%s: %s', file_path, warning.message)

